# What is this LEGO minifigure with huge teeth?

Tags: minifigure-identification

Does anyone know what minifigure this is?

[image]

Comment: Clearly the head belongs to a Sugar Plum Fairy from [_The Cabin in the Woods_](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/78861-msfc-the-cabin-in-the-woods/)...

Comment: Ah yes the legendary Lego Cthulhu Nightmare Minifig

Answer (score 19):

This minifigure is [Atlantis Hammerhead Warrior](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=atl017#T=P).

[image]

However it is missing its headgear - [Minifigure, Headgear Head Cover, Hammerhead Shark with Eyes and Light Bluish Gray Lines Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92943pb01&idColor=85#T=P&C=85) pictured here:

[image]